# Having trouble with HAVING COLUMN in mysql search

Tags: mysql, having-clause, grocery-crud

having trouble with HAVING clause of a column which exists

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM (`customers`)
LEFT JOIN `parent_companies` AS j2ee39a6a ON `j2ee39a6a`.`id` = `customers`.`parent_company_id`
WHERE `customers`.`is_approved` =  0
AND  `organization`  LIKE '%Pizza%'
OR  `title`  LIKE '%Pizza%'
OR  `picture`  LIKE '%Pizza%'
HAVING `customers`.`is_approved` = 0
```

I don't really understand as why it should have such issue - this is a query generated by Grocerycrud - automatically.. for searching a specific output..

Comment: What is the output or error generated?

Comment: What is that issue and trouble? you don't explained it!

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I dont see a need for the `HAVING` clause anyway because it is already served by the `WHERE` clause and there is no `GROUP BY` to go with `HAVING`. Try removing the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` is unnecesarry, because You do have that condition in `WHERE`

You May have wrong `count` because of brackets:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM (`customers`)
LEFT JOIN `parent_companies` AS j2ee39a6a ON `j2ee39a6a`.`id` =     `customers`.`parent_company_id`
WHERE `customers`.`is_approved` =  0
AND  (`organization`  LIKE '%Pizza%' **start_bracket_here**
OR  `title`  LIKE '%Pizza%'
OR  `picture`  LIKE '%Pizza%') ** close bracket here**
HAVING `customers`.`is_approved` = 0;  ** HAVING UNNECESARRY**
```